# div issue with position:absolute

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to place one div over the other. I've already accomplished this with `position:absolute;`, but the behavior is different on other screen resolutions—specifically, the `div` on top moves to the left. Can anyone figure out the issue? To better understand my question, see [this](http://www.gameboltz.com/game/346/alien-trench) page.

My CSS:

```
#flashplayercontainer{
    overflow: auto;
}
#flashplayer{
    width: 975px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#666666;
    border:#CC0000 thick 2px;
}
#adsbox{
    background: #222;
    width: 930px;
    height: 480px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 350px;
    left: 205px;
}
#cpmbox{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}

#cpmbox h2{
    color: #FFF;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#cpmbox a {
    color: #FC0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

</style>
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="flashplayercontainer">
    <div id="flashplayer"> 
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="adsbox" style="height: 400px;">
        <div id="cpmbox">
        <h2>Loading.......</h2>
            <script type="text/javascript">document.write("<iframe src='http://www.epicgameads.com/ads/banneriframe.php?id=yeA5z58737&t=300x250&channel=2&cb=" + (Math.floor(Math.random()*99999) + new Date().getTime()) + "' style='width:300px;height:250px;' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe>");</script>
            <p><a id="closeads">Close This Ads (<span id="covertimer">20</span>)</a></p>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your css. we need to make it Position  % with two div equally, I think its working perfectly.

```
#flashplayercontainer{
    overflow: auto;
}
#flashplayer{
    width: 975px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#adsbox, #cpmbox {
  width: 930px;
  height: 480px;
  border:#CC0000 thick 2px;
}
#adsbox {
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}
#cpmbox {
    left: 50%;
    position: relative;
    background-color:#666666;
    top: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 40px;    
    text-align: center;
}   
#cpmbox h2{
    color: #FFF;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#cpmbox a {
    color: #FC0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Three Things you need to change you code.

1) Make it Fixed instead of absolute

2) Left and Top make it % instead of px

like that:

```
#adsbox{
    background: #222;
    width: 930px;
    height: 480px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20%;
    left: 15%;
}
```

3) If you want also minimize and Maximize (window resizing) time. you have to write JS for 
position calculation of the Div i mean (left,top)

I hope its use full.

Comment: I have done the said things but the same issue renders. The div moves from the main div.My resolution is 1360x768. Its fine in my resolution but if i change the resolution then it changes its position. any suggestions

Comment: i post another answer check out.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the position:relative to `flashplayercontainer` div,

example:

```
#flashplayercontainer{
    overflow: auto; 
    position:relative;


}
```

And do the some pixels adjust for top and left in `ID adsbox`.